# Deploying a JSS App Next JS to Scaled Sitecore environment (Production)

Tags: jss, nextjs, deployment, sxa-jss

Hello Everybody I am working on a Next Js App over Sitecore it is working fine locally the app is created and working on Localhost but now I need deploy the App to production I have a Sitecore 10.3 Instance runinng Cm on a server and Cd on another server I can't find any method to deploy Next Js App on a scaled Sitecore instance Except Vercel and it is not allowed to use it in my company. Has anybody Faced this issue to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Vercel is a private platform created by the makers of Next.js.

So the creating app locally is free but when it goes to production it has to be hosted on the paid Vercel platform.

But there is a way of self-hosting Next.js with 3 different options.

- Node.js server
- Docker container
- A static export

One of the known option is below.

**Docker Image**

Next.js can be deployed to any hosting provider that supports Docker containers. You can use this approach when deploying to container orchestrators such as Kubernetes or when running inside a container in any cloud provider.

1. [Install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) on your machine.
2. [Clone our example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker) (or the [multi-environment example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker-multi-env)).
3. Build your container: `docker build -t nextjs-docker`.
4. Run your container: `docker run -p 3000:3000 nextjs-docker`.

Next.js through Docker supports all Next.js features. More details can be found below. I hope this will help.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying#self-hosting